# "Esception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. (mscorlib)" Importing a .bacpac in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure, import

I need to import a .bacpac exported from **Azure SQL Database** to recover the data out of Azure. I'm trying to import in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio like a "Data-tier Application" (like in the screenshot)
[image: importing]

The disk where I am saving the data and the logs has more space than necessary (the bacpac is <40Gb and the disk is 1TB) like the second screenshot.

[image: disks]

But the problem arrive in the last step, like in the third screenshot

[image: error]

Comment: SSMS is a 32bit application, so it's not really surprising. Could you try using a 64bit application instead, such as Azure Data Studio, to restore your Bacpac?

Comment: @Larnu I'm trying with Azure Data Studio right now. I think that you have reason

Comment: @Larnu You had the perfect answer! Do you want to put it in the answers?

Comment: you can be able to import .bacpac file into SQL server by using SSMS 18.12.1 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Larnu said, the problem was the SMMS, importing from Azure Data Studio worked perfectly.